# r - replace part of string after its matched

Tags: r, string, match

i'm trying to replace a part of a string which is matched like in the following example:

```
str1 <- "abc sdak+ 123+"
```

I would like to replace all `+` that come after 3 numbers, but not in the case when a `+` is coming after characters. I tried like this, but this replaces the whole matched string, when I only want to replace the `+` with a `-`

```
gsub("[0-9]{3}\\+", "-", str1)
```

The desired outcome should be:

"abc sdak+ 123-"

Comment: You need something called look behind `gsub("(?<=[0-9]{3})\\+", "-", str1, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could capture the 3 digits as a group (`(...)`) and the `+`, replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group and the `-`.  Just to make sure that there is no digits before the 3 digits, use either word boundary (`\\b`) or a space (`\\s`)

```
 gsub("\\b(\\d{3})\\+", "\\1-", str1)
```

-output

```
[1] "abc sdak+ 123-"
```

Comment: you sir are incredible, could you please say what the \\b \\d mean ?

Comment: @adl I updated with description

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `look-behind` ie is the `+` symbol preceded by 3 numbers? if so, replace it.

```
str1 <- "abc sdak+ 123+"
gsub("(?<= [0-9]{3})\\+", "-", str1, perl = TRUE)
[1] "abc sdak+ 123-"
```

Comment: great solution as well, I'm just strugling to understand the `look-behind` concept, but this solves what I needed

Comment: just out of interest how it would look like if the + is before the 3 numbers ?

Comment: @adl then you use a look-ahead. ie `\\+(?=\\d{3} )`